# Viewing a Sequential Timelog in Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm aware that org-mode has time clocking features via `C-c C-x C-i` to start the timer for a task and `C-c C-x C-o` to stop it.

**Question:** Is there a way to view -- across all of your agenda files -- a **sequential** timelog across all tasks? One that shows, for example, that you started the day doing Task A for N minutes, followed by Task B for M minutes, and so forth.

Comment: Have you tried the [clock report](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) using `:scope agenda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The agenda has a "log" mode that shows clocks and `CLOSED` timestamps in the agenda view.  While in an agenda, use `v l` or `v L` to activate "log" or "full log" view.